# How Self & Total time is calculated having Google Chrome's devtools profile report (cpuprofile file)

Tags: google-chrome, profiling, google-chrome-devtools, reverse-engineering

I'm writing tool to parse and extract some data from `cpuprofile` file (file produced when I save profile report) and I'm having some troubles with precision of Self & Total times calculations. So, time depends on the value from field `hitCount`, but. When `hitCount` is small (<300) the coefficient between `hitCount` and `Self time` ~1.033. But as `hitCount` grows, coefficient also grows.
So, when hitCount=3585, k is 1.057. When hitCount=7265: k=1.066.

Currently I'm using 1.035 as coefficient, I tried to minimize error on my sample data. But I'm not happy with approximation. I'm not familiar with Chromium code base to go and figure it out directly in the source code.

So how do I get Self time for function call having hitCount value?

Comment: Just in case you want my input, [*self time is worse than useless. See points 1 and 8.*](http://archive.is/9r927)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it's:

```
sampleDuration = totalRecordingDuration / totalHitCount
nodeSelfTime = nodeHitCount * sampleDuration
```

You can find it here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/sdk/CPUProfileDataModel.js&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=31

Comment: Do you know how the total time is calculated as well?

Comment: For anyone interested, I have found a solution to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40683161/1080221