# Calculate total time based on a .cpuprofile file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, profiling

I created a JavaScript CPU profile with Chrome and saved it as a `.cpuprofile` file. Using only this file, I want to calculate the "Total Time" for each node in this profile (as can be seen in the Chrome Profiler when you load the file.)

I found out how to calculate the "Self Time" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888211/how-self-total-time-is-calculated-having-google-chromes-devtools-profile-repo). Does anyone know how to extend it to the "Total Time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the Bottom Up Profile times. For anyone interested, I have created a **npm package called [cpuprofile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpuprofile)** that calculates all necessary times.